# ORA-12154 when trying to connect as SYSDBA

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

here is my environment

1. Oracle 12.2
2. NON-CDB
3. The oracle user is part of dba and oinstall group as follows

   $ id oracle
   uid=1000(oracle) gid=54322(dba) groups=54322(dba),54321(oinstall)
4. The ORAPW file has been created using ORAPWD utility
5. ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID set to DBALIAS

Here is my problem:

I can connect using following meethods

a. sqlplus SYS"@DBALIAS" as sysdba   ( it asks for password )

b. sqlplus SYS/PW@DBALIAS as sysdba

But when I use following, I get ORA-12154 error

sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
ERROR:
ora-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 2):

You commanded your shell to run `sqlplus` program and give it one argument `/ as sysdba`. The argument is a single word that contains spaces inside (that's what quotes do in shell). Thus sqlplus looks for a TNS name `/ as sysdba` and fails.

Instead try

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

That's a program name plus three separate arguments.

If you've really set `ORACLE_HOME=DBALIAS` then it will surely fail. You need to set it to precisely the same string as you used to STARTUP this database. Something like

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/dir/for/oracle/binaries
```

If you set it properly, you should be able to execute

```
"$ORACLE_HOME"/bin/sqlplus  / as sysdba
```